# Self-adhesive towel bars on tiles

Tags: bathroom, walls, tile, adhesive, bathroom-fixtures

I want to have a towel holder in the bathroom without drilling. If I use those self-adhesive racks on tiles would they create a problem to the tile? Does it depend on the type of tile? In my case it is those shiny ones (not sure how they are called)

Comment: Unless you are especially delicate with the towel rack, this is not going to work very well. To be clear, the issue will not be damage to the tile, rather it's whether it will hold at all

Comment: @Jeffrey: is there any other solution/approach then? I was concerned what happens to the tile when I strip the rack

Comment: The screw mounts are typically vertical or horizontal.  I just lined mine up between the tiles and drilled there.  If they are vertical mounts, you might need to cut the bar some to make it fit.  I have 8" tiles, and 24" towel bar, it happened to fit perfectly.

Comment: @rtaft: I really want to avoid drilling. Is there any other solution that does not involve drilling?

Comment: Assume that any towel bar is also a grab bar. Minimum is really good hollow wall anchors. Far preferable is screws into studs.

Comment: Answers below pretty much capture it, but there are free standing towel racks if you're desperate.

Comment: There is another type of rack that does not use adhesive tape but is based on vacuum but I can't recall the name

Comment: If used just as a towel rack/holder, adhesive should be fine.  Problem is it weak if it used to prevent a slip/fall.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

You're probably fine.

---

> If I use those self-adhesive racks on tiles would they create a problem to the tile? In my case it is those shiny ones

It sounds like you have glazed ceramic or porcelain tiles. The glaze is glass so if some adhesive residue is left behind then it can easily be cleaned with a cleaner/solvent like Goo-Gone, Windex, acetone, brake cleaner, orange citrus, etc...

If you had a porous tile like granite with no glaze for some forsaken reason then I do not recommend putting adhesive on it.

Answer (score 1):

Self adhesive towel rack will not damage the tile, but it will leave gunk, that can be scraped off.

How long will it hold?

Who knows ?

If the tiles are mirror like surface it will hold longer than if they are rough.

Comment: For scrapping what should be used to avoid damage to the tile? The tiles are shiny ones

Comment: @Jim be careful with chemicals, they can stain, specially citrus based. For scraping use a plastic putty knife.